# How can I get a material that is Default and not asset?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: The material is Default]

With this script I can get all the materials assets and change the shader for each material.
The problem is with materials that are defaults I can't find/get them.

```
[MenuItem("Assets/Get Type")]
    public static void GetTypes()
    {
        var materials = GetAssetsOfType<Material>(".mat");

        foreach(Material mat in materials)
        {
            Shader s1 = Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipeline/Lit");

            if(mat.name.StartsWith("Default"))
            {
                defaultMaterials.Add(mat.name);
            }

            mat.shader = s1;
        }
    }

    public static T[] GetAssetsOfType<T>(string fileExtension) where T : UnityEngine.Object
    {
        List<T> tempObjects = new List<T>();
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath);
        FileInfo[] goFileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*" + fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        int i = 0; int goFileInfoLength = goFileInfo.Length;
        FileInfo tempGoFileInfo; string tempFilePath;
        T tempGO;
        for (; i < goFileInfoLength; i++)
        {
            tempGoFileInfo = goFileInfo[i];
            if (tempGoFileInfo == null)
                continue;

            tempFilePath = tempGoFileInfo.FullName;
            tempFilePath = tempFilePath.Replace(@"\", "/").Replace(Application.dataPath, "Assets");
            tempGO = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(tempFilePath, typeof(T)) as T;
            if (tempGO == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (!(tempGO is T))
            {
                continue;
            }

            tempObjects.Add(tempGO);
        }

        return tempObjects.ToArray();
    }
```

I tried using name :

```
if(mat.name.StartsWith("Default"))
```

but that return no results.

Comment: I think I should get the Materials as ahredMaterials that's why it's not getting the default ones. but I'm not sure how to do it with this code and if this is the solution but in any case in editor script I should use sharedMaterial and not material but not sure how to do it.